# SELECT Between dates almost working

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, select

My problem is likely all about date formatting in a `SELECT`.

In an asp file I open an ADO Recordset wanting to retrieve rows of a MS SQL table that fall between `date1 (08/15/2013)` and `date2 (08/22/2013)` (i.e., the previous 7 days from today's date.)

The `SELECT` does retrieve the appropriate 2013 rows but also retrieves rows going back to 08/15/2012.

Here is the SELECT:

```
oRS.Source = "SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE entry_Date BETWEEN '" & resultLowerDate & "' AND '" & resultCurrentDate & "' AND entry_Status <> 'INACTIVE'"
```

resultLowerDate = 08/15/2013 and resultCurrentDate = 08/22/2013.

The table is set up as follows with resultCurrentDate = "08/22/2013":

```
entry_Status    entry_Date (varchar)    LastName    FirstName   SELECT Result
INITIAL     08/15/2012      Smith       Jim         YES
INACTIVE    08/21/2012      Green       Tom         no
INITIAL     08/22/2013      Jones       Mary            yes
FOLLOWUP    08/22/2013      Jones       Mary            yes
FOLLOWUP    08/22/2013      Brown       Sally           yes
FOLLOWUP    08/22/2013      Smith       Jim         yes
```

Any thoughts as to why the `INITIAL 08/15/2012` row gets selected along with the other rows that meet the `SELECT` query?

Comment: WHY is entry_Date a varchar???

Comment: If @AaronBertrand won't plug his own articles, I will. **Please** read [Choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) and [mis-handling date/range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries). It is probably worth reading the entire bad habits to kick series. They are all spot on, and if everyone read all of them there would be a lot less questions on Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STOP STORING DATES IN VARCHAR COLUMNS! And STOP CONCATENATING STRINGS, USE PROPER PARAMETERS.

Sorry to yell, but we are getting multiple questions a day where people use the wrong data type for some unknown and probably silly reason, and these are the problems it leads to.

The problem here is that you are comparing ***strings***. Try:

```
"... WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, entry_date, 101)" & _
     " >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & resultLowerDate & "', 101)" & _
" AND CONVERT(DATETIME, entry_date, 101)" & _
     " < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & resultCurrentDate & "', 101))"
```

Or better yet, set resultLowerDate and resultUpperDate to YYYYMMDD format, then you can say:

```
"... WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, entry_date, 101) >= '" & resultLowerDate & "'" & _
" AND CONVERT(DATETIME, entry_date, 101) < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '" & resultCurrentDate & "'"
```

Note that I use an open-ended range (>= and <) instead of BETWEEN, just in case some time slips into your VARCHAR column.

Also note that this query could fail because garbage got into your column. Which it can, because you chose the wrong data type. My real suggestion is to fix the table and use a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column.

Comment: I have been sidelined on this issue for some time.  However, today I have reviewed your suggestion and taken your advice.  I have modified the appropriate table columns to Date and Time types.

Comment: @user2033850 Great! Better late than never. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your entry_Date column is a varchar field and not an actual date is the problem. If you cast it to a datetime during the select, you'll get the results you expect.

```
select *
from aTable
where cast(entry_Date as datetime) between '08/15/2013' and '08/22/2013'
```

[Sql Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d36c/3)

Comment: CAST won't work well if the user is running with SET LANGUAGE BRITISH or SET DATEFORMAT DMY. You should use convert with a style, and any string literals that aren't explicitly converted should be in ISO format (YYYYMMDD).

Comment: That's true, and I would generally do something like this: cast(convert(varchar, entry_Date, 101) as datetime), but omitted it for this example.

Comment: If entry_date is already a string, converting to varchar ([with no length???](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)) with a style of 101 does nothing. (And that expression still fails if language is British or dateformat is DMT.) Why not just `convert(datetime, entry_Date, 101)`?

Comment: I've always used that syntax to omit the timestamp from a date, but I like the brevity of your solution, and it should save me some keystrokes in the future (muscle-memory notwithstanding).

Comment: `SELECT cast(convert(varchar, '08/15/2013 13:45:26.013', 101) as datetime)` yields `2013-08-15 13:45:26.013` (when it doesn't fail due to language or dateformat settings!) so I'm not sure how you omit the timestamp that way. Also [there are much more efficient ways to trim time from date without using string functions](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime).

Comment: The "where cast(entry_Date as datetime) between '08/15/2013' and '08/22/2013'" works for the string dates in the table I am using.